# How to edit text file in server using python

Tags: python, linux, server, automation, file-handling

I want to edit a line in a text file in a Linux server using python. The process involves following steps

1. Telnet to the server (using telnetlib)
2. Go to the required directory
3. open the text file in the directory
4. set or unset the flag (YES or NO) of the variable in the text file based on the requirement
5. save the file and exit

I'm able to automate until step 2. However, I'm stuck at step 3 through 5.

I tried to mimic the steps I follow manually (using vim editor). But I'm not able to perform the 'ESC', replace and ':wq!' steps. Is there an alternative procedure to edit the file or any ways to improve upon  mimicking the manual process

I have added my code here

```
host = input("Enter the IP address:")
port = input("Enter the port:")
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host,port)
tn.write(b'\n') 
tn.read_until(b"login:") 
tn.write(b"admin" + b'\n') 
tn.read_until(b"Password:") 
tn.write(b"admin" + b'\n') 
tn.write(b"version" + b'\n')
tn.write(b"path/to/file/" + b'\n')
# OPEN THE FILE and SET or RESET THE FLAG and CLOSE
with in_place.InPlace('filename.txt') as file:   
    for line in file:
        line = line.replace('line_to_change', 'changed_data')
        file.write(line)
print('Task executed')
```

I tried using the in-place library to set the flag but the programme is looking for the file in my local machine rather in the server. So it throws an error message indicating that the file is not present.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to connect to your remote server, the rest should work as follows:

```
with open('path/to/file','r') as fr:
    data = fr.readlines() # returns list of lines
    changed_data = ["changed_data\n" if line=="line_to_change\n" else line 
                   for line in data]

with open('path/to/file','w') as fw:
    for line in changed_data:
        fw.write(line) # write the lines back to the back
```

Comment: It only appends to the existing text which is not the desired task. I want to replace a line and overwrite the existing file. I think the file has to be closed after writing f.close()

Comment: `r+` should overwrite the file. Are you using the right mode?

Comment: @Ganesh, I've updated the answer and checked it on my local machine. Let me know it it doesn't work for you...

Comment: the code rewrites the entire txt file with juts this line -'the_line_you_want_to_change'. FYI I'm not giving any path to the file, I''m just giving the file name

Comment: @Ganesh updated my solution, please check it.
The `path/to/file` is the file full location. If you run your python code from within the folder where your file exists, you can put there the `filename`

Comment: the code is executing the perfectly in my local machine. But fail to do the task in the server. In fact, it is creating a file and exiting the programme. I have added my code.